# Grub prompt after upgrade to 11.04

Tags: server, grub2

I realize that there are a lot of information on here/Google about this, but I think my problem is different.

[image: grub]

I upgraded 9.10 -> 10.04 -> 10.10 -> 11.04. 11.04 failed and I was stuck at the grub prompt. As you can see in the photo, I'm having a hard time loading anything from the disk.

I have three disks, /dev/sdc being the OS disk on which I have Ubuntu Server. This is a pure Ubuntu box.

Please help :'(

Comment: Have you tried the well known livecd+`chroot` method to restore grub?

Comment: I haven't seen a complete guide for this yet. Firstly, what live CD would I need? 11.04? Someone suggested that the alternate live CD is required, but I can't find it anywhere on ubuntu.com anymore. Is it as easy as `mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt; chroot /mnt; grub-update;`?

Comment: Not exactly so easy: see here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#ChRoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I booted the Ubuntu Server 11.04 CD and chose Rescure console. Clicked <kbd>Esc</kbd> until the main menu came up. Then selected `Execute a shell`.

[image: rescure mode]

I followed the instructions over at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#ChRoot like @enzotib suggested. These are the commands I used, which are modified for the BusyBox shell.

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do mount $i /mnt$i -o bind; done
chroot /mnt
/usr/sbin/update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-install /dev/sdc
reboot
```

After the reboot I was presented with

```
error: no suitable mode found
```

Yay. After a couple of reboots and some searching I came to understand I just had to wait, then Ubuntu would boot. After it did, I logged in and ran `update-grub` and then rebooted. Problem solved! Thank you @enzotib.