# Weird looking screen after Ubuntu Server 11.04 boot

Tags: server, boot, screen

[image: weird screen]

I got this after upgrading to 11.04 [with some issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53702/grub-prompt-after-upgrade-to-11-04). It must be tty7, since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> does nothing. I can change to tty[0-6] to make the screen look normal, and changing back makes the screen black.

What is happening here? It's like it thinks I have X installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporarily edit your grub boot settting: remove `vga=something` and replace it with `nomodeset`. If you can boot normally to the desktop, do your troubleshooting and perhaps install/uninstall proprietary graphics driver or maybe remove any unsuitable graphics option.

Comment: No desktop, no graphics drivers, no X. This is (most of the time) a headless server ;-) But I will try `nomodereset`.

Comment: The kernel now has KMS (kernel mode setting), that uses the in-kernel graphics drivers to attempt to initialise any discovered graphics hardware.  If your device has a graphics adaptor (likely, as you've attached it to the monitor), the kernel will try to do something (although it may not select the optimal driver, or may be hopelessly confused).